# Pagekite error: FAIL: localhost:8080 is down

Tags: php, webserver, tunnel, pagekite

When i try to create a tunnel to my localhost:8000 with `$ pagekite.py 8080 xxxx.pagekite.me`, i get a error when someone trys to connect: (FAIL: localhost:8080 is down). I created the server on my local machine with: `$ php -S localhost:8080`. When i try to access to the site on my local machine with http://localhost:8080, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your webapp is probably listening on IPv6 localhost (::1) and pagekite.py is trying to connect to IPv4 localhost (127.0.0.1).

Forcing your webapp to listen on 127.0.0.1 should fix this.

```
$ php -S 127.0.0.1:8080
```